# Is there is a way to add Html <pre> into JSON file

Tags: json

Below JSON file, I would like to create line break by putting the content into JSON using "pre", Is this possible,

```
 {
  "Name": "<pre>Hello, How are You?
            I am Good<pre>",
  "Age":  12
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification of [`JSON`](http://json.org/) doesn't support multiline texts.

But you can use use the `\r` and the `\n` character to create a line break in the text.

```
{
    "Name": "<pre>Hello, How are You?\r\nI am Good<pre>",
    "Age":  12
}
```

Be aware of that the line break character is different on unix platforms.

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.